# How to update multiple cells in google sheets via Sheets Api?

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am using the following code in a PHP server to update values in cells `A4` & `A7` of a Google Sheet:

```
$values = array(
    array('1234'),
    array('abcd')
);

$range = array(array('Sheet1!A4'),array('Sheet1!A7'));

$data = [];
$data[] = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange([
    'range' => $range,
    'values' => $values
]);
// Additional ranges to update ...
$body = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateValuesRequest([
    'valueInputOption' => $valueInputOption,
    'data' => $data
]);
$result = $service->spreadsheets_values->batchUpdate($spreadsheetId, $body);
```

On running this request, the following error is received:

```
"error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"range\" at 'data[0]': Proto field is not repeating, cannot start list.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"range\" at 'data[0]': Proto field is not repeating, cannot start list.",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

What is the correct way to make a Google Sheets API request to update multiple discontinuous cells at once in PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved the issue by posting the data in the following format:

```
$data = [
    [
        'range'=> 'Sheet1!A4',
        'values'=> array(
        array('1234')
        )
    ],[
        'range'=> 'Sheet1!A7',
        'values'=> array(
        array('abcd')
        )
    ]
];
// Additional ranges to update ...
$body = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateValuesRequest([
    'valueInputOption' => 'USER_ENTERED',
    'data' => $data
]);
$result = $service->spreadsheets_values->batchUpdate($spreadsheetId, $body);
```